# Is it possible to re-number ids of BTRFS snapshots created via Snapper?

Tags: linux, btrfs, snapper

It is not big problem, but it will be really better to manage, if I can re-number it and all holes are gone.

So numeration will be again 1,2,3 and instead of 17,99 and so on.

```
  # | Type   | Pre # | Date                          | User | Used Space | Cleanup | Description      | Userdata
----+--------+-------+-------------------------------+------+------------+---------+------------------+---------
 0  | single |       |                               | root |            |         |                  |         
17* | single |       | Wed 13 Sep 2023 04:55:19 EEST | root |   8.55 MiB |         |                  |         
99  | single |       | Wed 13 Sep 2023 06:06:31 EEST | root |  21.70 MiB |         |                  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps to do it (renaming 17 to 1):

1. edit the file `/.snapshots/17/info.xml` using `sudo`
2. search the tag `<num>` and replace the number 17 with 1;
3. `sudo mv /.snapshots/17 /.snapshots/1`

You're done!

Comment: It looks as a working solution. It can be necessary to edit grub-snapshot.cfg if number is used there as well. Great!